# What is the difference between SharePoint workflow and Nintex workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I always use Visual Studio for designing workflows.I have seen if we install Nintex package we can design workflows. What is the difference between SharePoint workflow and Nintex workflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SharePoint and Nintex workflows are very different. Nintex workflows is a third-party tool which helps you do more with less efforts. As I understand, you are more or less acquinted with SharePoint workflows and know its features. You can find info about features of Nintex workflows [here](http://www.nintex.com/en-US/Products/Pages/NintexWorkflow.aspx). Also, you can download the trial version of Nintex Workflows to try it yourself.

Comment: I don't have working knowledge in sharepoint work flows.Now i am trying to study it.Is it able after installing nintex work flow we can design work flows from sharepoint UI?

Comment: Yes, you can use browser based drag-and-drop workflow designer if you use Nintex. But if you want to study I would suggest take a look at SharePoint Designer workflows first (2013 based), because it is out-of-the-box feature and it is free. SPD workflows are easier to understand than VS ones (especially in comparision with 2010 VS WFs). Also, try not to use 2010 WF platform (it is still available in SP2013, but is deprecated).